# matTooltip, not showing at correct place, when rendering inside *ngFor, and TR > TD

Tags: angular

I am trying to use matTooltip, inside *ngFor, HTML structure is like Table > TR> TD, in td i am using matTooltip, but it is showing way away from actual position, please see screenshot.

HTML is like this:

```
                 <ng-container *ngFor="let row of timesheetMatrix | keyvalue">
                  <tr>
                    <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 0)"></td>
                    <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 1)"></td>
                    <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 2)"></td>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let dayVal of row.value; let i = index;">
                      <td [class.isHolidayOrWeekend]="i > 4">
                        <span>{{dayVal?.text}}</span>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="dayVal?.description?.length > 0;  trackBy: trackByFn">
                          <span>
                            <mat-icon class="hasDescription" matTooltip="'dayVal?.description'"  #tooltip="matTooltip">info</mat-icon>
                          </span>
                        </ng-container>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
                      </tr>
                 </ng-container>
```

Please help.

[image]

Comment: use `matTooltipPosition`   https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

Comment: remove single quotes from matTooltip value so that your actual value will show

Answer (score 0):

use `matTooltipPosition` https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let row of timesheetMatrix | keyvalue">
              <tr>
                <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 0)"></td>
                <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 1)"></td>
                <td [innerHTML]="getTdTitleTextForProjectTaskActivity(row.key, 2)"></td>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let dayVal of row.value; let i = index;">
                  <td [class.isHolidayOrWeekend]="i > 4">
                    <span>{{dayVal?.text}}</span>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="dayVal?.description?.length > 0;  trackBy: trackByFn">
                      <span>
                        <mat-icon class="hasDescription" [matTooltip]="dayVal?.description" [matTooltipPosition]="after" #tooltip="matTooltip">info</mat-icon>
                      </span>
                    </ng-container>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
                  </tr>
             </ng-container>
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz for same?